# Mock tgz, tar, gz files for unit testing in C#

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have been using System.IO.Abstractions for unit testing.
https://github.com/tathamoddie/System.IO.Abstractions

Example from what i am doing now with System.IO.Abstractions

```
MockFileSystem selectedFileSystem = new MockFileSystem(
               new Dictionary<string, MockFileData>
               {
                    { @"c:\test\", new MockDirectoryData()},
                    { @"c:\test\test.txt", new MockFileData("file content")},
               });
```

I am searching for a way to mock tgz, tar and gz files in the same way as files and directorys in the code above so i can test my extract methods.

I want to do something like this, is there a nuget packet or some other solution?

```
MockTGZ mytgz = new MockTGZ(
               new Dictionary<string, MockFileData>
               {
                    { @"folderInsideTGZ\", new MockDirectoryData()},
                    { @"test.txt", new MockFileData("file content")},
               });
```

Comment: What's holding you back? Can you add TGZ compressed data to a MockFileData class, and then run your extraction logic against that?

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do, but as an alternate wouldn't simply doing checksum magic do the trick?

Comment: How about *not* using such abstractions, and using an actual test.gz file instead? Or *not* depending on the file names for testing? If you want to test compression, use *streams*. If you want to test a GZipStream, use a `MemoryStream` instead of a `FileStream` as the underlying stream.